# On my C# properties in my class

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, data-annotations

I have this class

- I want to validate the EmpType property so that can only take a value from the enum EmploymentType.
- And then I want to validate EmplyomentNumber so that it starts with an "E" and includes 3 numbers
- And then the salary property must be bigger or equal to 0.

  ```
  public class Employment
  {
      [Required, StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage ="Name must be between 3 and 50 characters long.")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public EmploymentType EmpType { get; set; }
      public string EmplyomentNumber { get; set; }
      public decimal Salary { get; set; }
  }
  public enum EmploymentType
  {
      Full,
      Temporary,
      Internship
  }
  ```

Comment: i dont know how to do it i have tried to find the answer but dont get nowhere

Comment: Are you using MVC, or plain old Forms?

Comment: You are using the RequiredAttribute. Are you looking at information about other attributes (such as RangeAttribute) or about writing your own attributes? Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate `EmployeeNumber`, then use `RegularExpressionAttribute`. For example:

```
[RegularExpression("^[Ee]\d{3}$")]
public string EmployeeNumber{ get; set; }
```

As for the `EmploymentType`, the question here is how do you let users select this value? Is it via a dropdown list, radio button, etc.? If you are populating a dropdown list with the values in the enum, I think that all you need is to decorate your `EmpType` property with `[Required]` attribute.

For `Salary` property you can use `[Range(0.1, 100000.0)]`. The first value represents the minimum allowed value, and the latter is the maximum allowed value. Both values are required. You cannot specify just the minimum value without maximum, and vice versa.

For more information on available data annotations have a look at the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a validation with auto-implemented properties. You should create a property with a field:

```
public class Employment
{
    [Required, StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage ="Name must    be between 3 and 50 characters long.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private string _emplyomentNumber;
    private decimal _salary;


    public EmploymentType EmpType { get; set; }

    public string EmplyomentNumber 
    { 
        get { return _emplyomentNumber; }
        set
        {    
            // validate here!
            _emplyomentNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal Salary 
    { 
        get { return _salary; } 
        set
        {
            // validate here!
            _salary = value;
        }
    }
}

public enum EmploymentType
{
    Full,
    Temporary,
    Internship
}
```

You don't need a validation for the `EmploymentType` unless some of the enum values are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For validating enumeration, you should do this:

```
    public EmploymentType EmpType 
    {
        get
        {
            return empType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (EmploymentType.IsDefined(typeof(EmploymentType), value))
            {
                empType = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    private EmploymentType empType;
```